# Copying files without knowing drive letter

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make the setup of new PC's we get easier and started playing around with copying group policies. I put all the instructions (copying the folder and executing the files) in a `.bat`, but now I have the problem that it only works when the drive letter of the stick I'm using is `E:\`. Is there any way to dynamically adjust the drive letter and not hard code it?

It's just a few lines of code since most is happening inside the `.exe`

```
xcopy "E:\LGPO" "C:\LGPO\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
cd C:\LGPO
lgpo.exe /g C:\LGPO\backup
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually need to copy the folder? The good reasons to run a binary from a specific location are rare. I see no reason why the binary couldn't be run from the stick, unless you want it on disk for later use of course.

Comment: I don't need to copy the .exe specifically, but one of the gpo's is setting a custom background and the folder has the background image.

Comment: is the script on your USB?

Comment: Yes it's on a usb, that's why I used E:\

Comment: then just do `xcopy "%~dp0\LGPO" "C:\LGPO\" /s/h/e/k/f/c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply copy to the path from where the script is located. This case usb uaed (drive), Also use `/d`
 with the `cd` command, as you change drives.

```
xcopy "%~d0\LGPO" "C:\LGPO\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
cd /d C:\LGPO
lgpo.exe /g C:\LGPO\backup
```

`cd /?` specifies:

> Use the /D switch to change current drive in addition to changing current directory for a drive.

The variable `%~d0` will use drive of the path of the batch file, where `%~dp0` is the drive\path.. So in this case, your batch file is inside the folder, we only need to use the drive `%~d0`

Comment: So far didn't have any problems using the script without /d

Comment: probably not, but this is the proper way, somewhere you will have an issue without.

Comment: I just tried using "\LGPO"  and "%~dp0\LGPO" and none of them worked. Changed it to "D:\LGPO" (different pc without optical drive") and it worked again. Something doesn't seem to be right

Comment: Bottom of script add `echo %~dp0 & pause` let me know what it prints to screen.

Comment: I just executed it on a different PC and it fails in the first line instantly.

Comment: Ok. Add the echo line to the very top.

Comment: xcopy "F:\LGPO\" "C:\LGPO\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
Invalid path

Although F:\LGPO is the right path. This doesn't happen when I hard code "F:\LGPO"

Comment: Probably don't have permission to create files directly on C:

Comment: When I use "%~dp0/LGPO" it says xcopy "F:\LGP\\LGPO" in the cmd window

Comment: If i didnt have permissions it wouldnt work when i hard core the path

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>xcopy "F:\LGPO\\LGPO" "C:\LGPO\" /s/h/e/k/f/c`
Thats whats in the cmd window in the first line using ""%~dp0\LGPO""
And then it says ´File not found´

Comment: Is that after the edited code? That is not possible as there is no path added

Comment: No. Copy edited code in answer please. And remove the echo line we tested with.

Comment: Not possible. Please recopy the answers code. And remove the echo line

Comment: `%~dp0` changed to `%~d0`

Comment: That seems to have fixed the problem, gonna verify on a few different systems now, but i feel optimistic

Comment: I will explain in the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Remove the drive letter from your batch script.
When you start the batch from the USB-Stick, the current drive is the USB-Stick.

```
xcopy "\LGPO" "C:\LGPO\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
pushd C:\LGPO
lgpo.exe /g C:\LGPO\backup
```

If you really need the current drive letter, you can use `%~d0`.

Comment: Giving it a try now. This would be an incredibly easy solution ^^

Comment: Why change drive letter and cd in 2 steps when you can `cd /d` ?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard You're right, I was too lazy. I changed it to `pushd` instead

Comment: @Marc I tested it successfully. Where it fails for you?

Comment: @jeb the problem is that he has the script inside of LGPO folder, not in the root of the USB :) ammended your code to adjust to that.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thanks, but I think it, my version was better, because `"\LGPO"` points always to `"<currentDrive>:\LPGO"`, but `"..\LPGO"` is a relative path, when the batch resides in `"F:\xyz\scripts\"` it points to `"F:\xyz\LPGO"`

Comment: @jeb yes, I get your point, but the script is in `D:\LPGO\script.cmd` meaning doing `xcopy \LPGO..` will try and copy from inside the dir attempting to find the dir..

Comment: perhaps a better option for your example would have been to do `cd \\`` then `xcopy \LGPO` but neither of us knew at the time that the script was in the actual dir to be copied :)